# In Scripture - Was Prophecy That was Spoken in Good Faith, ever Corrected?

Tags: pneumatology, prophecy, reference-request, prophets, visions

---

## 1. Question - A Reference Request:

Is there any occasion in scripture where someone prophesied to another and made an honest mistake, or were later corrected?

**Note:** This is apart from any discussion regarding false prophets.*

---

## 2. Context:

"Schools of Prophecy" often claim that ***"Words of Knowledge" to others*** can be mistaken, or subject to personal fallibility, ([Shawn Bolz on Accountability / Fallibility](https://youtu.be/hjdzacbfSrE?t=3672));

Is there a Biblical Basis for this?

**Other Closely Related Questions:**

- https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/50906/in-scripture-was-gods-voice-ever-mistaken-when-spoken-privately
- [Historically, How was “Word of Knowledge” Understood?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/23539/historically-how-was-word-of-knowledge-understood)
- [What is the Biblical Basis for "Schools of Prophecy"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/50899/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-schools-of-prophecy-where-people-learn-to-pro)
- [How to know whether God truly spoke to you?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16207/how-to-know-whether-god-truly-spoke-to-you?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What is the Biblical basis for testing the truthfulness of every statement made by Prophets or Apostles who have been confirmed as 'real'?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14628/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-testing-the-truthfulness-of-every-statement-made)

Comment: elika kohen:  I changed the wording for clarity. Please roll back my change if you disagree, or make any alteration you wish.  I also removed some of the bolding, which can be hard to read when used in excess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example that comes to mind is in Acts chapter 21. The context is, Paul is traveling to Jerusalem, where he knows he will be imprisoned.

> We sought out the disciples there and stayed with them seven days.
>   **Through the Spirit they urged Paul not to go on to Jerusalem.** When it
>   was time to leave, we left and continued on our way. All of them,
>   including wives and children, accompanied us out of the city, and
>   there on the beach we knelt to pray. After saying goodbye to each
>   other, we went aboard the ship, and they returned home.
>
> We continued our voyage from Tyre and landed at Ptolemais, where we
>   greeted the brothers and sisters and stayed with them for a day.
>   Leaving the next day, we reached Caesarea and stayed at the house of
>   Philip the evangelist, one of the Seven. He had four unmarried
>   daughters who prophesied.
>
> After we had been there a number of days, **a prophet named Agabus came
>   down from Judea. Coming over to us, he took Paul’s belt, tied his own
>   hands and feet with it and said, “The Holy Spirit says, ‘In this way
>   the Jewish leaders in Jerusalem will bind the owner of this belt and
>   will hand him over to the Gentiles.’”**
>
> When we heard this, **we and the people there pleaded with Paul not to
>   go up to Jerusalem. Then Paul answered, “Why are you weeping and
>   breaking my heart? I am ready not only to be bound, but also to die in
>   Jerusalem for the name of the Lord Jesus.” When he would not be
>   dissuaded, we gave up and said, “The Lord’s will be done.”**
>
> Acts 21:4-14 (NIV) (emphasis mine)

While the information being prophesied by Agabus in this case was not false (verse 4 may be talking about only a temporary halt), the disciples certainly interpreted and reacted to the prophesy wrongly in their response to it. Paul had to correct them all, including Philip.

Comment: Joel - Accepted; **A.)** You said : `While the information being prophesied by Agabus in this case was not false`;  And, Agabus didn't actually tell Paul not to go ... **B.)** I had been hoping for an example of where a genuine prophet was corrected, because their prophecy was actually wrong; **C.)** But - I think this is probably the closest Scriptural example; Thanks!