# What is the Biblical Basis for considering techniques like cold reading to be prophecy?

Tags: biblical-basis, prophecy, spiritual-gifts

Some modern day charismatic teachers exercise a kind of prophecy that seems very similar to non-Christian psychic readings or secular cold reading techniques.

One example is [Shawn Bolz prophesying](https://youtu.be/hjdzacbfSrE?t=4486), compared to [Deren Brown explaining psychic readings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X56Kmbgn6dE&feature=youtu.be&t=500).

What Biblical support do these Christians give for calling these techniques prophecy, and what Biblical support do they give for practicing them?

---

*Closely Related To:*

1. [What is the biblical basis for modern-day prophets?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34214/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-modern-day-prophets)
2. [What is the Biblical Basis for "Schools of Prophecy"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/50899/what-is-the-biblical-basis-for-schools-of-prophecy-where-people-learn-to-pro)